# C# ExecuteReader has rows but result view initially with question marks

Tags: c#, datareader

ExecuteReader has rows but initially when i hover and look at result view it has question marks for all the rows.  Then when i go back in a second time to hover it says enumeration yielded no results.   the HasRows is true however.  I'm also getting my output parameters fine, but not the result set from the select statement. I'm executing a sql server stored proc.  the SP executes fine in management studio.  And again i am getting the output parms, just not the result set.

```
internal static CrossWalk Create(string senderId, string ediType)
{
    var connection = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["caeCustom"];

    DbCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(); 
    cmd.CommandText = "emb_edi_xwalk_select";
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.AddParameter("@pSENDER_ID", senderId);
    cmd.AddParameter("@pMAPPING_TYPE", ediType);
    var delegateId = new SqlParameter
    {
       ParameterName = "@pDELEGATE_ID",
       SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int,
       Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
    };
    cmd.Parameters.Add(delegateId);           

    var crossWalk = new CrossWalk();
    var dbFactory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(connection.ProviderName);
    using(var sqlConnection = 
          dbFactory.CreateConnection(connection.ConnectionString))
    {
       cmd.Connection = sqlConnection;

       using (var sqlReader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
       {
           if (sqlReader.HasRows)
           {
               while (sqlReader.Read())
               {
                   //Mapping of AAA values will be AAA03~internal_value --> 
                    loop~external_value
                   //i.e. AAA03~1008 --> 2010EA~51
                   string key;
                   string value;
                   if (sqlReader["element"].ToString() == "AAA03")
                   {
                       key = string.Join("~", 
    sqlReader["element"].ToString(), sqlReader["internal_value"].ToString());
                       value = string.Join("~", sqlReader["loop"].ToString(), 
    sqlReader["external_value"].ToString());
                   }
                   else
                   //Normal xwalk mapping will be loop+element~external_value 
                   --> internal_value
                   //i.e. 2010ANM101~X3 --> 3
                   {
                       key = string.Join("~", sqlReader["loop"] + 
    sqlReader["element"].ToString(), sqlReader["external_value"].ToString());
                       value = sqlReader["internal_value"].ToString();                                
                    }
                   crossWalk._lookups.Add(key, value);
               }
           }
           sqlReader.Close();
       }
       crossWalk.DelegateId = 
       Convert.ToInt32(cmd.Parameters["@pDELEGATE_ID"].Value);
    }
   return crossWalk;
}
```

Comment: Since in ADO.NET a DataReader is only one-directional, it makes sense that after you've gone through all the records, the reader should return no further records. What happens when you try to output data to the Console? to a file? Also, there's a lot going on here in your code; I strongly suggest that you simplify it to do nothing other than 1) open a connection, 2) create a command, 3) call ExecuteReader and 4) iterate through the reader.

Comment: Side note: `if (sqlReader.HasRows)` is *redundant* as well as `sqlReader.Close();`

Comment: Also, why are you using `dbFactory.CreateConnection(connection.ConnectionString))` and not `new SqlConnection`?